# How to initialize cursor correctly?

Tags: android, database, kotlin

I am trying to call a database query and access the data.The query works fine and the cursor is moved to firs in android device1 but not in android device2. In device2, it is showing this error

```
E/CursorWindow: Failed to read row 0, column -1 from a CursorWindow which has 2 rows, 7 columns.
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.stock_design, PID: 25451
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.stock_design/com.example.stock_design.Edit}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col -1 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:150)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
```

This is the database controller class

```
val getEdit:List<Item_Edit> get(){
    val db=context.openOrCreateDatabase(REAL_DATABASE, Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null)

    val query ="With cte as (SELECT * FROM Transaction_table ORDER BY (CASE WHEN isbn = '$edt_isbn'  AND location = '$edt_lc' AND branch = '$edt_br'THEN 2 ELSE 1  END), branch) SELECT T.isbn,T.branch,T.location,T.qty,M.article,M.description,M.price FROM cte T LEFT JOIN Master M  WHERE T.isbn = M.isbn"

    val cursor = db.rawQuery(query,null)
    println(edt_isbn)
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {

        do {
            seItem.add(Item_Edit(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("branch")),
                cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("location")),
                cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("isbn")),
                cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("article")),
                cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("description")),
                cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("price")),
                cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("qty")) ))

        } while(cursor.moveToNext())
    }

    else{
       ck_edt = "false"
    }
    db.close()
    return seItem
}
```

Comment: If you have updated the database schema and installed the application without using the proper updation code.

Comment: clear your data on Device 2
try this command on terminal adb shell pm clear "your package name"

Comment: @MachhindraNeupane I tried that, but did not solve the problem. When I change the query  to ```SELECT T.isbn,T.branch,T.location,T.qty,M.article,M.description,M.price FROM Transaction_table T LEFT JOIN Master M  WHERE T.isbn = M.isbn```,it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I changed using from column name to column index and it is working fine. I really don't get it why it works on device1 and not in device2 when I use column name. At least the problem is solved. I changed to

```
 seItem.add(Item_Edit(cursor.getString(1),
                cursor.getString(2),
                cursor.getString(0),
                cursor.getString(4),
                cursor.getString(5),
                cursor.getString(6),
                cursor.getString(3) ))
```

Answer (score 1):

Does this error only happen on device2?

If so, then the error could be in that device's schema.

```
failed to read row 0,column -1
```

means that you are trying to read from a column that doesn't exist.

Check if you have any spelling mistakes in the column names. Also, column names are case-sensitive so check that as well.

Comment: yes, it is only on device2. If the column name is wrong it should not be able to call the query but instead it returns the row and column numbers ```Failed to read row 0, column -1 from a CursorWindow which has 2 rows, 7 columns```